# Spring integration : Is it possible to implement a Transaction in a ServiceActivator method?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, spring-integration

I would like to annotate my ServiceActivator with Transactional as below :

```
@ServiceActivator
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public Message<MyResult> populate(List<Things> th) {

// inserting in database

// try { throwing an exception } catch...

//doing other stuffs (insersions)

}
```

I expect to rollback the insersions after throwing an exception.

Unfortunately it dosen't work, I got the insersions in database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it should work; did you add `@EnableTransactions` to a `@Configuration` class?

Comment: The transaction is rolled back when you do that explicitly or throw an exception from the method. Show the code of your method. Somehow I see there `catch` ...

Comment: @ArtemBilan the catch only log the exception message, which is in my case : "Luck of information"

Comment: @GaryRussell You're right! I didn't find the enabling config of annotation based declarative Transaction Management. I've just added <tx:annotation-driven> in my xml config, and it works.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this topic, I'm providing the answer here. Even if it looks like hijacking it from Gary Russell. Although we are from the same team.

So, the `@Transactional` as many other aspects in Spring must be *enabled*. For this purpose there is a special `@Enable...` annotation - `@EnableTransactionManagement`. This one scans for the `PlatformTransactionManager` bean and applies AOP Advices to the methods marked with the `@Transactional`.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction) for more information.